# git gc failure refers to object hash that's not referenced anywhere

Tags: git, git-gc

Recently, I noticed that when I've been `git pull`ing my repo, it's been doing a `git gc` every single time. So I tried to run `git gc` manually, which gave me this error:

```
fatal: bad object 76cab35e0e21b7cf0bc8416661a67fbfb7f0e4ba
error: failed to run repack
```

I then tried to search `.git/packed-refs` and `.git/objects/` and `.git/index` for this hash (and even tried just searching the filenames and contents of my entire `.git/` directory for this hash), but it *never appears*. Neither does it appear in `git fsck --full` (which I guess probably refers to some files in `.git/`, so that makes sense).

How do I fix this? (I'm using `git 2.3.2`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because reflog has references to entries that have somehow vanished from the filesystem. Running `git gc` with `--prune="0 days"` will remove all references that are older than now that aren't tracked in the remote origin, and should fix the issue.